# A MonotonicFrameClock is not available in this CoroutineContext when I try to change ModalBottomSheetState from ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change state of ModalBottomSheet from Jetpack Compose in ViewModel.

Here what I do, I have a ViewModel, something like this:

```
class MyViewModel() {
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    val bottomSheetDialogState = ModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
    )

    fun showBottomSheet() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            bottomSheetDialogState.show()
        }
    }
}
```

and inside Fragment:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun ShowUnableToChangeDialog() {
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = viewModel.bottomSheetDialogState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 10.dp, topEnd = 10.dp),
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.White,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 1.dp)) {
                Column {
                }
            }
        }
    ) { }
}
```

and when I call `showBottomSheet()` I catch this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A MonotonicFrameClock is not
> available in this CoroutineContext. Callers should supply an
> appropriate MonotonicFrameClock using withContext.
> at androidx.compose.runtime.MonotonicFrameClockKt.getMonotonicFrameClock(MonotonicFrameClock.kt:114)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.MonotonicFrameClockKt.withFrameNanos(MonotonicFrameClock.kt:85)
> at androidx.compose.animation.core.SuspendAnimationKt.callWithFrameNanos(SuspendAnimation.kt:286)
> at androidx.compose.animation.core.SuspendAnimationKt.animate(SuspendAnimation.kt:229)
> at androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable$runAnimation$2.invokeSuspend(Animatable.kt:291)
> at androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable$runAnimation$2.invoke(Unknown
> Source:8)
> at androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable$runAnimation$2.invoke(Unknown
> Source:2)
> at androidx.compose.animation.core.MutatorMutex$mutate$2.invokeSuspend(InternalMutatorMutex.kt:119)
> at androidx.compose.animation.core.MutatorMutex$mutate$2.invoke(Unknown
> Source:8)
> at androidx.compose.animation.core.MutatorMutex$mutate$2.invoke(Unknown
> Source:4)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)

I tried to use other coroutine scopes, for example with Dispatcher.Main and etc, but exception is still the same. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It needs to be called within the scope of Composition.

Check please this link: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#remembercoroutinescope

Comment: Indeed, thank you. A bit strange behavior - you can use other states in ViewModel, but not this one =(